# Parameterizing for a Complex Line Integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, complex-numbers

I'm working my way through a textbook on complex variables and I'm having trouble with the initial set-up for this problem. I have to compute the line integral

$$ \int_{\gamma}^{^{}}e^{z}\;dz$$ where $\gamma$ is the line segment from $0$ to $z_{0}$.

I know what to do once the problems been parameterized into x(t) and y(t) so that I can use       z = x + iy. The part I keep getting stuck on is on getting the i to cancel out in z because most of the problems i've done so far have had i remain in z.

This is probably something really simple but i'm just not getting it so I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Why does the $i$ have to “cancel out”, and what does that even mean? In this case, just take $z=tz_0$ with $t\in[0,1]$. Assuming $z_0=x_0+iy_0$, this means $x(t)=tx_0$ and $y(t)=ty_0$, if I understand your notation. Note too that you then have $dz=z_0\;dt$.

Comment: My understanding is that $0$ and $z_{0}$  are the endpoints of the line segments so for some t-values, x(t) and y(t) plugged into z=x(t)+iy(t) give those endpoints.
So for the x(t), y(t) you have wouldn't the endpoint be $x_{0} + i y_{0}$ instead of the $z_{0}$ value specified?

Comment: They’re the same thing. $z_0=x_0 +iy_0$. Let me spell it purr explicitly as an answer:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along $\gamma$, you have $z=tz_0$ ($0\leq t\leq 1$).

Then $e^z=e^{tz_0}$ and $dz=z_0\;dt$.

The integral becomes
$$\int_{\gamma}e^z\;dz
=\int_{t=0}^{t=1}e^{tz_0}z_0\;dt$$

It’s fine to integrate this directly—it doesn’t matter that there are complex numbers involved. You don’t have to take it all the way down to real and imaginary parts immediately. In fact it’s much easier to integrate it in this form (the same rules apply even with complex constants involved). Continuing:

$$=\left.\frac{e^{tz_0}}{z_0}z_0\right|_{t=0}^{t=1}$$
$$=\boxed{e^{z_0}-1}$$

Now at *this point* you may want to write this as
$$e^{x_0}\cos y_0-1 +ie^{x_0}\sin y_0$$
but I would just leave it in the boxed form above.

Comment: Alright I definitely get it now. Thank you for taking the time to write that out.

Comment: One last thing: In your original statement of the problem I changed the name of the path from your “$y$” to “$\gamma$”. That’s a lowercase Greek gamma, not a lowercase Y. They do look somewhat similar, but I’m guessing it’s supposed to be a gamma (that’s standard notation for some reason). Just saying, @rezark .